# How can I make a test that passes only when an assert fails?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, verilog, system-verilog

I have a module that has an assert when a pre-condition that should never occur is detected. How can I write a test that passes based on this assert failing when I give the module invalid inputs?

In the past, I've done this sort of thing using the Verilog PLI. I'm learning SystemVerilog, and I'd prefer to use some Verilog or SV construct and avoid having to run a separate program, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're thinking about this the wrong-way-round.

> I have a module that has an assert when a pre-condition that should never occur is detected. How can I write a test that passes based on this assert failing when I give the module invalid inputs?

This is sounding very confused. A test should pass if the module does the right thing for the input it's been given. Giving a module invalid inputs shouldn't cause a test failure if the module does the right thing in response. The right thing might be flagging the error, raising an interrupt or maybe just ignoring the input.

Hence, you should never need to require a test to fail.

I think what you mean is:

> I want to test a module with "invalid" stimulus, and I want to make sure the module notices (e.g. by flagging an error)

In which case the assertion becomes:

```
assert @some_event (invalid_input |=> error_caught);
```

You then use coverage to ensure that a test caused the assertion to complete at some point.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with macros. Define a macro for normal operation and another one for test mode:

```
`define MY_ASSERT(X) assert(X)
`ifdef TEST
  `define MY_ASSERT(X) if (!(X)) $display("TEST PASS")
`endif
```

Sample test with sim results on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/92

Here is another example that includes a custom message:

```
`define MY_ASSERT(X,MSG) assert(X) else $error(MSG)
`ifdef TEST
  `define MY_ASSERT(X,MSG) if (!(X)) $display({"TEST PASS with assert:", MSG})
`endif
```

Use it like this: `` `MY_ASSERT(in == 1'b1, "Bad input"); ``

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Don't do this! A single check should never cause a "TEST PASS" message to be displayed. You should only signal a test passing at the end of the test when nothing unexpected has happened.

Comment: Yes. In a complete test environment, you should have a callback to track which assertions fired (instead of a simple `$display`). Then, at the end of the test, you can check whether the assertion that you expected to fire actually fired.